# how to group by in LINQ and not select all columns

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I am trying to write a LINQ query which is complex for me now since I am a newbie to LINQ.

I have a table like below...

```
UserId | CompanyId | ProblemDescription | CreatedTime      | TimeSpentMins
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1      | 95        | Sysmtem is crashed | 2016-01-01 15:23 | 25
1      | 95        | Total is incorrect | 2016-01-01 15:45 | 45
```

I want to write a LINQ query that will do the job below. CreatedTime has date and time but I want to group it by only date.

```
SELECT UserId, CompanyId,CreateTime Sum(TimeSpentMins)
FROM TransactionLogs
GROUP BY UserId, CompanyId, Convert(DATE,CreatedTime)
```

How can I write this LINQ? I wanted to put my code below but I got nothing :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use the [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method and use [EntityFunctions.TruncateTime](http://EntityFunctions.TruncateTime) method to get only the date part:-

```
var result = db.TransactionLogs
               .GroupBy(x => new 
                            { 
                               CreateTime = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.CreatedTime),
                               UserId,
                               CompanyId 
                            })
               .Select(x => new
                           {
                                UserId = x.Key.UserId,
                                CompanyId = x.Key.CompanyId,
                                CreateTime = x.Key.CreateTime,
                                TotalTimeSpentMins = x.Sum(z => z.TimeSpentMins)
                           });
```

Comment: It gives me the following error. The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
var result = db.TransactionLogs
    .GroupBy(_ => new {
        _.UserId, _.CompanyId, DbFunctions.TruncateTime(_.CreatedTime)})
    .Select(_ => new { 
        _.UserId, _.CompanyId, DbFunctions.TruncateTime(_.CreatedTime), 
        Total = _.Sum(t => t.TimeSpentMins)});
```